# How make MySQL query for text split by ,

Tags: php, mysql, select, separator

I have mysql DB. Row look like

```
name | name | groups | name
==============================
item | item | 1,3,5  | item
```

**I need make query for:**

Select all rows, that have **group = 3**. How I make this ? Is there any simple query string

Thank you very much !

Comment: [Normalize your database](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Your table design is bad, which is why you have this issue. Therefore you have no choice but create a procedure (or PHP script) that gets each row, splits the string, checks for the value and returns it if the group you are looking for is in there.

Comment: Okay, i get it, I need make next table name 'groups_assocc' and there make connections between two table (row / id´s).  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing better then normalizing your table, but if you still need to do like this way here is one way to this,

Try `where` clause like this

```
 $group = 3;
 where groups IN("$group",",$group","$group,",",$group,")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$search = 1;// or whatever you want to search
    select * from table_name where groups like '%,$search,%' or groups like '$search,%'  or groups like '%,$search'
```

or you can try this **simple one**

```
select * from table_name where find_in_set('3',groups ) <> 0
```

for more info about `find_in_set` please read http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php